# Skype for Business Web SDK samples not working

Tags: office365, skype, lync, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have downloaded the Skype Web SDK samples from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn986863%28v=office.16%29.aspx), but I can't make them work. I have registered a trial Office 365 account (`dotnetsolutionsdemos.onmicrosoft.com`) and I have a user there (`adam@dotnetsolutionsdemos.onmicrosoft.com`).

If I run the desktop version of Skype for Business then I can log in with my account so it seems that the Lync service does work.

I have installed the Skype for Business Web App Plug-in, put the sample code under IIS and opened it via a browser. Then I tried to sign in with my aforementioned account and it doesn't work. The ajax loader image is displayed and never disappears.

Upon inspecting the network traffic, I found the following:

There is a GET request to `https://lyncdiscoverinternal.dotnetsolutionsdemos.onmicrosoft.com/xframe` which fails. The request fails with some name lookup failure or something, doesn't even return an HTTP response.

There is another request to `https://lyncdiscover.dotnetsolutionsdemos.onmicrosoft.com/` which returns `403 Forbidden`.

Upon navigating to this address I find that the SSL cert doesn't match the URL.

I have tried it with IE/Chrome/Firefox, all the same. Also I haven't configured anything after registering the Office 365 account just used the default settings. As I said the desktop Skype for Business logs in just fine.

What am I doing wrong, how can I make this work?

Please find captured images below.

**Network traffic:**
[image: Network traffic]

**Wrong cert:**
[image: Wrong cert]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the Skype Web SDK doesn't support Office 365 accounts - only on-premises or hosted (in a Data Center. etc.):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn705760(v=office.16).aspx

Microsoft have indicated that Office 365 **will** be supported, but haven't yet provided any public guidance as to when as far as I know.

I'd recommend keeping an eye on the MSDN forums for updates on when this will be supported.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=SkypeWebSDK&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc

Comment: is this answer still valid ? Currently the Skype Web SDK supports Office 365 accounts

Comment: At the time it was, but not anymore, as the SDK does support 365 now. There's a good overview at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline for anyone who wants to learn more.