# Skype Web SDK - Skype For Business Online

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

I am trying to work with Skype Web SDK with Skype for Business  Online and I downloaded the [samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986863(v=office.16).aspx) provided by Microsoft, but I get an error when trying to log in (similiar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201291/skype-for-business-web-sdk-samples-not-working)). I found out in the same post that the SDK doesn't support SfB Online. I also found the same answer from the [Skype Web SDK FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn705760(v=office.16).aspx).

But then I spoke to a company that specializes in corporate Skype implementation saying that SfB Online is supported by the SDK, which was contrary to what I found out.

So my question is: Is SfB Online supported by the SDK?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the S4B online accounts are not supported by the Web SDK until now. it's only supported by Lync (Client) 2013 SDK.

See the comparison table here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt124990.aspx

Update:

As of March 24 the skype web sdk now supports SfB online accounts, it has 2 versions GA and public preview and they're both support online accounts but vary in capabilities, please see the differences here:

[Skype Web SDK Production Use Capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt670739(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I hadnt noticed the table.