# How can I login in Skype web SDK with Office365 credentials?

Tags: office365, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype4java

I want to build customer chat support using Skype Web SDK **(Skype for Business)**. Is it possible to build?

I am using Java EE.

I have downloaded Skype Web SDK sample and hosted locally. 
Right now, I am not able to login with Skype web SDK sample Because my office 365 account is taking RSA code as a security. Or Right Now I am not able to login with developer sandbox because UCWA Interactive Demo Service is down.

Can you help me how can I login?

Is there any system or company existed which are using Skype web SDK for Customer Chat Support? If Yes, which?

[Skype for Business Web SDK samples not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201291/skype-for-business-web-sdk-samples-not-working?rq=1)
As per the link Office 365 Users are not allowed.

How can I login with Office 365 credentials?

Comment: Are you using the normal Skype (SfC = Skype for Consumer) or Skype for Business (=SfB). Your posting contains both versions as tags, however there is a difference in both products.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention..I was talking about Skype for Business

Answer (score 0):

For logging into Skype For Business using Skype Web SDK, first you need a server that serves the request and handles the communication. Now that server can be hosted at your own organisational premises or you can use the Skype For Business Online servers provided by Microsoft. 
If you want to use the servers at your organisational level, you will need to set it up for Skype for Business.
If you want to use Microsoft servers, you would have to link your Office 365 account with an Azure Active Directory and then use the Azure Ad to login. You cannot directly login with Office 365 credentials before setting up Azure AD and registering your app on Azure.

Please provide more clarity so that I can help you.